Let A be an infinite set and E the set of equivalence relations on A. Prove that E is equinumerous to the power set of A.
So far, I understand that I have to create a bijection between E and P(A), but I haven't been able to find such. One idea I had is to take the set P of equivalence classes of A and show that it is equinumerous to E and to P(A), and by transitivity of the relation equinumerous, E would be equinumerous to P(A), but I'm sure there's an easier way.
Any help is appreciated!

What do you mean by "equivalence classes of $A$"? Did you mean to say "the set $P$ of partitions of $A$"?

Creating a bijection between $E$ and $P(A)$ would be a hard way to do it. If the following theorems are available, you should use them to make your task much easier: (1) The Cantor–Schroeder–Bernstein equivalence theorem, which says that if there are injections $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ then there is a bijection $h:X\to Y$. (2) The theorem which says that, if $X$ is an infinite set, then there is a bijection between $X$ and $X\times X$.

Let $E$ denote the set of equivalence relations. An injection $E \to P(A \times A)$ is clear (recall a relation is just a subset of $A \times A$ by definition). For an injection, $P(A) \to E$ a naive attempt is mapping a subset $S$ of $A$ to the equivalence relation defined by grouping everything in $S$ and having the identity relation on everything else. This does not work as every singleton is mapped to the identity relation. This can be fixed by instead working with the domain $P(A \setminus \{x\})$ (for a fixed element $x \in A$), so that we have a map $P(A \setminus \{x\}) \to E$. Specifically, we map $S$ a subset of $A \setminus \{x\}$ to the equivalence relation defined by grouping members of $S \cup \{x\}$ and having the identity relation elsewhere. This is clearly injective.

By the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstien theorem, it suffices to that show that there are injections $P(A) \to E$ and $E \to P(A)$.
Since $A$ is infinite, there is a bijection between $A \times A$ and $A$. So, the obvious inclusion $E \subseteq P(A \times A)$ induces an injection $E \to P(A)$.
Also, there is a bijection between $A+A=A \times \{0, 1\}$ (the disjoint union of $A$ and itself) and $A$. So, it suffices to show that there is an injection from $P(A)$ to the set of all equivalence relations on $A+A$ (which, of course, is in bijection with the set of all equivalence relations on $A$).
Given any subset $B \subseteq A$, map $B$ to the equivalence relation on $A+A$ where $(a, x)$ is identified with $(b, y)$ if and only if $a=b$ and either $x=y$ or $a \in B$. Then, this defines an injective map from $P(A)$ to the set of all equivalence relations on $A+A$, since $B$ could be recovered from the corresponding equivalence relation as the subset of elements $a \in A$ for which $(a, 0)$ is identified with $(a, 1)$.
